# Nested Group BY Sql Query

Tags: sql-server

I have following three tables in my sql server db

1 ->    GroupList

```
GroupID || GroupName
```

2 ->    MachineList

```
MachineID   || GroupID  || MachineName
```

3 ->    CaptureLogs

```
LogID   || MachineID    || VoilationWord
```

I need a query to get the following report

```
GroupName   || MachineCountInGroup  || TotalLogCountByMachinesInGroup
```

Guys, Please help me out.

Comment: You should really put some data and expected results if you want us to give you a correct answer. The third column you are asking for is not very clear. Is it the count of all log of all machine of the group?

Comment: @user3567971: It looks like you want a line per Group and then count the machines in that Group. That's okay so far. But then you want a "TotalLogCountByMachinesInGroup". I would understand a "TotalLogCountInGroup", but count by machines? Do you mean the avarage count of logs per machine in a Group? Or what else? And I agree with Raging Bull and Frazz; you could show some effort instead of having *us* do all the work *including guesswork*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
  select GroupName ,
    (select count(1) from  MachineList where GroupID = grp.GroupID ) as    
     MachineCountInGroup   ,
   (select count(1) from  MachineList 
   inner join  CaptureLogs 
   on  CaptureLogs.MachineID=MachineList .MachineID   
   where GroupID  = grp.GroupID ) as TotalLogCountByMachinesInGroup
   from  GroupList grp
```

I am sure that there is better way but this will work.

Comment: Man you Rock !!. Thanks a lot, exactly what i was looking for.God bless you.

Comment: @kabs You are welcome. As i said i am sure there is better solution but sql is not my best part :)

Answer (score 0):

Without data it's difficult to say for sure, but I would guesstimate that something like this might be what you're after?

`SELECT 
  DISTINCT gl.groupid ,
  gl.groupname, 
  COUNT(ml.MachineId) OVER (PARTITION BY gl.groupid) AS MachineCountInGroup,
  COUNT(cl.LogId) OVER (PARTITION BY cl.MachineId) AS TotalLogCOuntBYMachinesInGroup
FROM dbo.GroupList AS gl
JOIN dbo.MachineList AS ml ON ml.groupid = gl.groupid
JOIN dbo.CaptureLogs AS cl ON cl.machineid = ml.MachineId`

This will give some data that appears like:

`groupname, machinecountingroup, totallogcount... 
    A       3                       1
    A       3                       2
    B       2                       2`

if you only want one row for A, you'll need to adjust the

`COUNT(cl.LogId) OVER (PARTITION BY cl.MachineId) AS TotalLogCOuntBYMachinesInGroup`

line to something like

`COUNT(cl.logid) OVER (PARTITION BY gl.groupid) AS TotalLogCOuntBYMachinesInGroup`

That will give you only one row for A and one for B.

`A   3   3
B   2   2`

So seeing as I don't know exactly what you're after, this is the best I can do (again - test data would be nice)

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared the complete script and then the best solution for the requirement.

Script to create tables

```
create table GroupList
(GroupId int primary key, GroupName varchar(50) not null);

create table MachineList
(MachineId int primary key,
 GroupId int not null,
 MachineName varchar(50) not null
);

Alter table MachineList
Add foreign key(GroupId)
references GroupList(GroupId)

Create table CaptureLogs
(LogId int identity(1,1) primary key,
 MachineId int not null,
 VoilationWord varchar(50) not null
);

Alter table CaptureLogs
Add foreign key(MachineId)
references MachineList(MachineId);
```

Now script to insert some sample data in tables:

```
Insert into GroupList Values(1,'Group 1'),(2,'Group 2');

Insert into MachineList 
values(1,1,'Machine 1'),(2,1,'Machine 2 of 1'),(3,2,'Machine 3 of 2'),(4,2,'Machine 4 of 2'),(5,2,'Machine 5 of 2');

Insert into CaptureLogs
    (MachineId, VoilationWord)
select MachineId, 'First Word from ' + MachineName from MachineList
union all
select MachineId, 'Second Word from ' + MachineName from MachineList
    where MachineId > 1
union all
select MachineId, 'Third Word from ' + MachineName from MachineList
    where MachineId > 2
union all
select MachineId, 'Fourth Word from ' + MachineName from MachineList
    where MachineId > 3
union all
select MachineId, 'Fifth Word from ' + MachineName from MachineList
    where MachineId > 4;
```

Now to get your required data, you need to run the simple code. I think it is the best for this requirement.

```
Select gl.GroupName, count(distinct ml.MachineId) MachineCountInGroup, 
        count(LogId) TotalLogCountByMachinesInGroup from GroupList gl
        inner join MachineList ml on gl.GroupId = ml.GroupId
        inner join CaptureLogs cl on ml.MachineId = cl.MachineId
        group by gl.GroupName;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

SELECT
  g.GroupName,
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.MachineID) AS MachineCountInGroup,
  COUNT(*)                    AS TotalLogCountByMachinesInGroup
FROM CaptureLogs l
JOIN MachineList m ON m.MachineID=l.MachineID
JOIN GroupList   g ON g.GroupID=m.GroupID
GROUP BY g.GroupName

As an aside, I expect that counting l.MachineID provides the engine with better opportunities to optimize the access than counting m.MachineID. The 2 are identical anyway, since there is an INNER JOIN.

Tested on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3374e/3), as I have no SQL Server installation of my own.

Comment: Have you tried to execute a query like that? I mean with out grouping? This will not execute.

Comment: I fixed it, by adding the GROUP BY. Is there anything else that is wrong?

Comment: I have now tested it and fixed it. Sorry if I seem stubborn, But I'd rather fix than delete. The solution is structurally different from yours and I think it should survive. Thanks for the input.